# Eclipse considers "src" to be a part of the package name after importing existing project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported an Eclipse (Mars) project on another Computer with the latest version of Eclipse. Now Eclipse considers the `/src/` folder as a part of the package name. E.g. `src.org.domain.subdomain` instead of `org.domain.subdomain`.

[image: The package names in the project view]

I can rename the package, removing `src` but then Eclipse will actually move the folder to the root folder, but I want the source to stay in `src`.

Is there a way to fix this? How does Eclipse determine what the root folder of the source is, is it possible to set this manually? Has this behavior changed from Mars to the latest version?

Comment: you can manipulate from .class file. Find your project location and search for .class file edit the file and change it accordingly.

Comment: Go into your project settings and add `src/` as a source directory

Comment: Your source folders got messed up. Select Project->Properties->Build Path, remove the existing source folders, select the folder "src".

Comment: Right click on your project and go to Build path -> configure build path. There you can st your source directories

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [daniu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2837741/daniu)'s comment I could resolve my issue, I'll quote it:

**Select Project->Properties->Build Path, remove the existing source folders, select the folder "src".**

Thanks!

Comment: I had to remove the "src" folder, open src/main, and select the "java" and "resources" folder